# Why value of "id" is not accesible in function displayx()?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getx(x) {
  const id = 'x';
  console.log(id);
}


function displayx() {

  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" onclick="getx(1)">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    Default radio
  </label>
</div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3" id="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal" onclick="displayx()">
        Button1
</button>
```

When clicked on radio button,function `getx()` executes properly, but after clicking on radio button, when clicked on normal button `(id="button")` getting error in function `displax()`

Error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined`

I tried var also instead of const but still function displayx() is not getting value of "id".
Thanks in advannce.

Comment: Either change `const id` do `var id` or move `const id` outside of the function

Comment: const id is block scoped, it is local to your function block, to solve it put the `const id = "x"`inside your global scope, outside of the function block

Comment: @DominikMatis Since `var` is function-scoped, changing `const id` to `var id` would have the same issue. If `const id` was moved outside, it would probably need to be made `var` or `let` since OP probably wants to re-assign it in the function call, which wouldn't be possible with `const` ;-)

Comment: @NickParsons yep u r correct

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickParsons, By declaring var id; out side the function solved my problem.